# Angular Sort Items in Table with MatSort

Tags: angular, typescript

That is to sort the items in the columns

```
 export class ObjectComponent implements OnInit {


  displayedColumns: string[] = ["id", "name", "vorname", "mobileNumber", "secondMobileNumber", "email", "secondEmail", "roomNumber", "task", "Notes", "Edit", "Delete"];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource/*<ContactListEntry>*/(FORMULARLIST);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator);

    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

    const sortState: Sort = { active: 'name', direction: 'desc' };
    this.sort.active = sortState.active;
    this.sort.direction = sortState.direction;
    this.sort.sortChange.emit(sortState);
  }
```

Thats the Html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort >

        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.id}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.name}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="vorname">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Vorname</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.vorname}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="mobileNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Mobilfunknummer 1</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.mobileNumber}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="secondMobileNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Mobilfunknummer 2</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.secondMobileNumber}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email 1</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.email}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="secondEmail">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Email 2</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.secondEmail}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="roomNumber">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Raumnummer</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.roomNumber}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="task">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Aufgabe</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.task}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Notes">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Notes</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">{{formular.notes}}</td>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="Delete">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Delete</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">
                <button (click)="openDialogDelete(formular.id)" mat-mini-fab color="warn">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="Edit">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Edit</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let formular">
                <button (click)="openDialogEdit(formular)" mat-mini-fab color="black">
                    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </td>
        </ng-container>


        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons
        aria-label="Select page of formular elements">
    </mat-paginator>
</div>

<button (click)="openDialogAdd()" mat-mini-fab color="success">
    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Thats my array component

```
    export const FORMULARLIST: ContactListEntry[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Mustermann',vorname:'Max', mobileNumber: 123456, secondMobileNumber: 654321, email: 'MaxMustermann@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'MaxMustermannSecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'A101', task: "Rechenzentrum", notes: 'Notiz' },
  { id: 2, name: 'MMM',vorname:'nnn', mobileNumber: 111, secondMobileNumber: 222, email: 'mmm@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'mmmsecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'A102', task: "Rechenzentrum2", notes: 'Notiz' },
  { id: 3, name: 'EEE',vorname:'EEE', mobileNumber: 333, secondMobileNumber: 444, email: 'nnn@beispiel.de', secondEmail: 'nnnsecond@beispiel.de', roomNumber: 'B202', task: "Rechenzentrum3", notes: 'Notiz' },
];
```

Thats my contact-list.entry

```
export interface ContactListEntry {
id: number;
name: string;
vorname: string;
mobileNumber: number;
secondMobileNumber: number;
email: string;
secondEmail: string;
roomNumber: string;
task: string;
notes: string;
```

}

I want that when I click on the headings of the table that the items are arranged in the table.

The things should be arranged in the correct order by clicking on the heading and the other way around when I click on it again.

Comment: if you want that use matSortDisableClear: `<table mat-table ... matSort matSortDisableClear="true" >`, see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview#changing-the-sort-order)

Comment: That dont work. I cant sort the items